# Itunes connect change from last week

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, app-store-connect

In my iTunes connect developer profile, I see a change from last week, and just below it says a change next to the number of units sold. What is this "change"? Is this how many people uninstalled the app?

Answer (score 2):

No, its the difference between number of downloads last week and number of downloads this week.